# Получение пути к папке внутри проекта UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Я разрабатываю своё uwp-приложение и хотел бы использовать в нём свои специальные иконки. Я хотел бы часть этих иконок подгружать скриптом для биндинга в разных элементах. **Вопрос как мне получить путь к этой папке** `Assets/Icons/CategoryIcons`**?**

[image: Обозреватель решений моего проекта]

Я попробовал получать часть пути к проекту через:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path
```

Но оно предоставляет путь только к `LocalState` моего проекта где у меня нет этих файлов.

Answer (score 0):

[Ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#:%7E:text=Path%20(ms%2Dappx%20and%20ms%2Dappx%2Dweb)&text=That%20file%20is%20in%20a,physical%20file%20asset%20is%20retrieved.)

Нашел тут способ как добавлять путь к используемым внутри проекта файлам.

Вместо

`$"{Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path}/Assets/Icons/CategoryIcons"`

я использовал `"ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/CategoryIcons"`